# Geolocation returned location incorrect by 3 km

Tags: geolocation

I was wondering when I used the javascript geolocation it didn't pin point into my exact location.. this is thec ode I used that I got in w3schools..(http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

```
 <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

also with http://whereamirightnow.com/ it didn't point me exact location..

does anyone have an idea about my case?

Comment: You told us that it didn't pinpoint  your exact location. But what _did_ it do? Did it fail to call your function? Did it pass inaccurate data? Did it pass _no_ data?

Comment: it did pass the data but not my exact location...

Comment: What location did it pass? How inaccurate was the  location? Were you at a new address? (newer than a few years, for instance)

Comment: we lived in our place more than 20years. I didn't leave our place but the code function pin point a distance location about 3km away that no history that we lived on that place..

Comment: You're saying that the latitude and longitude it returned were off by 3km. Was one of the two off more than the other? Which browser were you using? You should try it with different browsers. Were you connected through an Internet Service Provider, through a cell phone, or what?

Comment: I used firefox and chrome.. I am using Internet Service Provider

Comment: I am using desktop..

Comment: As you're on desktop, maybe it's getting the location of your ISP? My desktop is stating I'm 293 miles (470km) away in a different country :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using an ISP connection and desktop computer the gelocation will be based on your IP address rather than say a GPS receiver or cell tower location that may be used on a mobile device. Some browsers will use different IP geolocation services but for example from the [Firefox Location Aware Browsing](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/) page:

> If you consent, Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless access points and your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this information to the default geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get an estimate of your location. That location estimate is then shared with the requesting website.
>
> Accuracy varies greatly from location to location. In some places, our service providers may be able to provide a location to within a few meters. However, in other areas it might be much more than that. All locations returned by our service providers are estimates only and we do not guarantee the accuracy of the locations provided. Please do not use this information for emergencies. Always use common sense.

So it will depend on how granular the location information is provided by your ISP. In my case gelocation reports my position as the local telephone exchange where the ADSL DSLAM is located, which is approximately five kilometers away.

Answer (score 0):

as the developer of [where am i right now](http://whereamirightnow.com), we're already said that our website use "any means necessary" to get your position.

IF you access our website from an GPS enabled smartphone / tablet, then You'll get the best position since the HTML5 geolocation will then get the location data from there.

If there aren't any GPS then, HTML5/W3C geolocation API (not my website, it's a feature built in by HTML5 Geolocation API) will try to determine the proximate location of your position, thus can be Wifi Location, CellPhone triangulation (if using wireless usb modem stick), or may even be IP froum your router/provider.

That's why Geolocation information will always have "accuracy" component, in which - in our website where am i right now, if it is less than 1000 metres (1Km), then we mark it with red color (poor accuracy).

the Geolocation is simply helpfull tool to get location for web based interface. the location data accuracy, however is independent from the API.

If you have any further question, please let me know, contact me from contact us section in bottom of the website.

Hope that's help :)

regards